# Sort multiple separate PHP arrays and keep keys in sync

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key, synchronization

I have three arrays that are synced with the same key and I need to natsort and apply array_values() to array1 while keeping array2 and array3 in sync with the new keys set for array1 by array_values().

I have looked around and can't find any methods used for keeping multiple array keys in sync after sorting one of them. Thanks in advance for any help with this problem.

```
-- array1 (unsorted)
Array (
  0 => OA.3,
  1 => OA.8,
  2 => OA.6,
  3 => OA.2,
)

-- array2 (unsorted)
Array (
  0 => 4,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 5,
  3 => 3,
)

-- array3 (unsorted)
Array (
  0 => 3,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 5,
  3 => 0,
)

-- array1 (natsorted)
Array (
  3 => OA.2,
  0 => OA.3,
  2 => OA.6,
  1 => OA.8,
)

-- array_values(natsort(array1))
Array (
  0 => OA.2,
  1 => OA.3,
  2 => OA.6,
  3 => OA.8,
)

--- needed result for array2/array3 ---
-- array2 (keys matching array1)
Array (
  0 => 3,
  1 => 4,
  2 => 5,
  3 => 1,     
)

-- array3 (keys matching array1)
Array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 3,
  2 => 5,
  3 => 1,
)
```

Is there some way to keep all three of these arrays in sync during the natsort() and array_values() sorting of array1? The final result of array2 and array3 show the new keys matching the final result of array1's sorting and re-keying.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what do you want as final output? I am having problems understanding your question.

Comment: @Viral Sorry I just updated the OP. realized it was a bit confusing after re-reading the post. Let me know if it's better

Comment: Yes, better now, also post array1 , 2 and 3 as a result of `var_export()`, not `print_r()`

Comment: @Viral ok just changed the output to var_export() for you also

Comment: I feel like i need to do this manually and ready the order of natsort with the keys somehow and store them in temp variables to apply them to the other 2 arrays but i cant even get my head around it. and im not the greatest with php so i wouldnt even know if its possible to read the order of natsort and store those numbers and their actual keys in a way to apply them without destroying the other 2 arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the keys of array A after the natsort, to sort the array B and C... Example:

```
<?PHP
function pre($a) { echo '<pre>'; print_r( $a ); echo '</pre>'; }
$a = array(
  0 => 'OA.3',
  1 => 'OA.8',
  2 => 'OA.6',
  3 => 'OA.2'
);
$b = array (
  0 => '4',
  1 => '1',
  2 => '5',
  3 => '3'
);
$c = array (
  0 => 3,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 5,
  3 => 0,
);
pre( $a );
natsort( $a );
pre( $a );
foreach( $a AS $key => $var ) {
    $bb[] = $b[ $key ];
    $cc[] = $c[ $key ];
}
echo '$bb:<br />';
pre( $bb );
echo '$cc:<br />';
pre( $cc );
?>
```

You can apply array_values() on array $a, $bb and $cc after the sorting is done.

Note: pre is just to print the array's inbetween and has no other function.

Comment: This seems pretty elegant and easy to read, I will try this in just a few and mark it as accepted if it all works out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, you can do the same for `$required_array3`

```
$required_array2 = array();

foreach ($your_array2 as $key => $value)
{
    $k = array_search($value, $your_array1); // Original array [unsorted]
    $required_array2[$k] = $value;
}
```